# Error when splitting columns with macro

Tags: vba

I'm new with VBA and I'll appreciate any help. I run a few macros in my document, and one of them is a macro to copy a column with names, paste it on next column right, and use texttocolumns to split it into two, names and last names. When the column it copies the names from is not empty, it runs fine, but if the range is empty it gives

> Run-Time Error 1004    TextToColumns method of Range class failed.

```
Sheets("PUNTA").Select
Range("C2:C45").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("D2:D45").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Columns("D:D").Select

Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Sheets("Tours").Select

End Sub
```

enter code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `Select` and test whether there are values in the column before using text to columns.

```
With Sheets("PUNTA")
    .Range("D2:D45").Value = .Range("C2:C45").Value
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("D:D")) > 0 Then
        .Range("D:D").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
            :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much Scott.....it did ti....!!!! I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @Gilbert please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.